# No reconoce js para la extension

Tags: javascript

Estoy probando como hacer extensiones para chrome y mi archivo html no reconoce el js

Archivo manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["https://*/*"],
    "js": ["app.js"],// este js si lo reconoce
    "css": ["app.css"]
  } ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "app.html",// este html si lo reconoce
    "default_title": "capture!"
  },
```

archivo app.html

```
<head>
    <script src="function.js"></script> // este archivo js no lo reconoce
```

la estructura del arbol es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con `../function.js/`

Comment: @alex55132 sigue sin funcionar, que podra ser

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que las rutas de los archivos estén mal, si sigue sin poder arreglarlo edite la pregunta y adjunte la estructura del "arbol" de archivos para ver si ese es el error @hubman

Comment: Porque no abres la consola y nos muestras que dice

Comment: con `./function.js` tal vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con estas una de estas dos opciones debería funcionarte:
Añadir la ruta en el archivo en el manifest.json

```
"js": ["app.js", "function.js"]
```

O cambiar invocarlo de esta forma:

```
<script src="./function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Te recomiendo también crear una carpeta js y meter ahí todos los archivos javascript para que te quede todo más ordenado, entonces para invocarlo solo tendrías que hacer :

```
<script src="js/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

En cuanto al type="text/javascript" no es necesario incluirlo ya que en html5 este es el tipo por defecto pero por compatibilidad con versiones antiguas del navegador siempre es mejor ponerlo.

Si lo anterior no te funciona intenta añadir tu archivo function.js en el manifest.json a los recursos accesibles

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["function.js"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Es importante tener en cuenta que el vincular archivos externos JavaScript ya sea en el `<head>` o antes de la etiqueta de cierre `</body>` depende del proyecto y/o la manera en la que estés trabajando tu código.

Intenta vincularlo antes de la etiqueta de cierre `</body>`
ó de la siguiente manera `<script src="./function.js"></script>`.